# String manipulation in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsarray, int

this is hard to describe but I am currently catching a string from a database, this string can be 1-4 characters long, however I am wanting to always display 4 characters, so if i get say a string back that is 34, i want it to be 0034.

I have set up a method to catch the string so now I just need to figure out how to do this. what I then plan to do is feed that string into a NSArray so I can send each [i'th] of the array off to 4 differetn methods that control animations in my app.

The reason its in string format is because I have had to bounce it round from hex, to int  to string for various formatting reasons within the application.

this is my code i have so far. Suggestions/solutions would be great thankyou, I am so new its hard to find solutions for stuff like string manipulation etc..

```
//... other method I am getting the string from/.
[self formatMyNumber:dataString];
///..


-(void)formatMyNumber:(NSString *)numberString{
    //resultLabel.text = numberString; //check to make sure  string makes it to here.
    //NSLog(@"hello From formatMyNumber method"); //check
}

//..
//the with send off each character to 4 animation methods that accept integers.
- (void)playAnimationToNumber:(int)number{
//...
```

//UpDated... weird stuff happening.
here is my method so far.

```
//Number Formatter
-(void)formatMyNumber:(NSString *)numberString{


    NSLog(@"This is what is passed into the method%@",numberString);
    int tempInt = (int)numberString;
    NSLog(@"This is after I cast the string to an int %i",tempInt);

    //[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat:@"%04d", numberString];
    NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%04d", tempInt];

    NSLog(@"This is after I try to put zeros infront %@",tempString);

    //resultLabel.text = tempString;
    //NSLog(@"hello From formatMyNumber method");
}
```

this is the output.

> [Session started at 2011-06-19
>   16:18:45 +1200.] 2011-06-19
>   16:18:54.615 nissanCode0.1[4298:207]
>   731 2011-06-19 16:18:54.616
>   nissanCode0.1[4298:207] 79043536
>   2011-06-19 16:18:54.617
>   nissanCode0.1[4298:207] 79043536
>   2011-06-19 16:18:54.617
>   nissanCode0.1[4298:207] hello From
>   formatMyNumber method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the number of zeros preceding your string goes there are a couple of ways to do this.  I'd suggest:

NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d",[dataString intValue]];

Comment: worked like a dream, thank you :) it was nice to see the difference in methods and try them all out, got the idea of whats going on now thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you could have the number in integer form instead of string form? If so, it's pretty easy to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d", number]`. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) for a list of the possible format specifiers.

Comment: ah cool.. this is kinda like c++.. I should have looked, thanks for that will try this out now :P

Comment: This dosn't seem to want to work its throwing back big numbers that don't mean anything.
I have tried a couple of ways.. but cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: Is your number an integer or floating-point value? If it's a float or double you have to use %04f instead... read the link I posted.

Comment: You mentioned above you were going to "just cast it to an int". You can't do this if you have a NSString pointer, you'll just be reading the pointer value. You have to use `[myString intValue]` as Dancreek said, or if you already have an int you should just use that.

Answer (score 1):

See what [stringWithFormat:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) can do.  I realize you mentioned your numbers are NSStrings, but if they were ints, or you convert them back to ints, the following may do the trick.  Modify the following to best suit your need:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d", number];
```